# How can I define a Javascript function that can be chained onto other Javascript libraries?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I define a method that can be chained to jQuery methods, or other libraries' methods ?

So let's say I have the following code:

```
var Calculator = function(start) {
var that = this;

this.add = function(x) {
    start = start + x;
    return that;
};

this.multiply = function(x) {
    start = start * x;
    return that;
};
```

I can then chain the methods as I wish to a Calculator object:

```
new Calculator(0)
    .add(1)
    .multiply(2)
```

But what if I'd want to chain a method named "my_method" on top of a jQuery object like so:

```
$(document).append("<p></p>").my_function();
$(document).my_function();
```

How would I define such a function ?
I tried adding `my_function` to the "Object" class, but then this doesn't apply to object arrays:

```
Object.my_function = function() {
     alert(this); 
     return this;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery lets you extend its object by adding properties to `jQuery.fn`.

So:

```
$.fn.my_function = function() {
    …
};
```

You can also extend jQuery’s object prototype with multiple properties using [`jQuery.fn.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fn.extend/).

As for other libraries — it varies! If their objects have a common constructor, you can generally put your methods on their prototype, which is incidentally the problem with your `Object` example; you need to put your method on `Object.prototype` for it to be part of the lookup chain.

Your own example can be rewritten as this, for example (which is actually preferred for “regular” “classes”):

```
function Calculator(start) {
    this.start = start;
}

Calculator.prototype.add = function(x) {
    this.start += x;
    return this;
};

Calculator.prototype.multiply = function(x) {
    this.start *= x;
    return this;
};
```

Comment: This makes sense, and I'm aware of that. But this is using jQuery's predefined `.fn` functionality. What I'm asking is related more to how you would actually define `$.fn` in the first place. So for example if I'm using yui, or d3js or other libraries, this wouldn't be applicable

Comment: @CosminAtanasiu: `$.fn === jQuery.prototype`. That’s the problem with your `Object` example, by the way: you need to put the methods on `Object.prototype` for them to be “inherited”.

Comment: No way! Thanks, the `Object.prototype` was what I was after. I'll accept your answer as soon as stack overflow lets me.